# How to make a MediaWiki User required to select license on file upload

Tags: mediawiki

It's the first time that I have had to set up a MediaWiki site and I am relatively new to it as a whole.

My problem is that users can upload files (only images in my case) without selecting one of the licenses in the drop down box on the Special:upload page, I have defined licenses though under MediaWiki:Licenses so there are licenses select-able. I would like the upload warning function to tell users that a license is required to upload a file (the same way you are warned the name is to short or whatever). The user must first pick a license before being able to continue.

I have searched around quite a bit and it doesn't seem as easy a changing a variable somewhere. If the solution is something that I should have known I apologize for posting a stupid question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've not checked again but this is not really possible with MediaWiki:Licenses alone IIRC. You can however easily set MediaWiki:Licenses to that the default/fallback "license"/tag is something clearly bad like {{DELETEME}} and then set up an [AbuseFilter](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter) rule to prevent the upload in question. AbuseFilter is very useful, so I recommend trying it anyway.

Alternatively, you can install the [UploadWizard](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UploadWizard), which is very cumbersome to configure but is quite good at enforcing Wikimedia-specific habits like template/copyright paranoia. ;-) Then you can set $wgUploadNavigationUrl to point to UploadWizard, or even restrict Special:Upload visits to privileged users.